# Best practice for ownership of a UINavigationController in a navigation based app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

My small app is growing more sprawling and I'm looking for some best practice advice on the management/ownership of view controllers and navigation controllers.

Here's what I'm doing now:

1. AppController is a singleton that creates and owns a UINavigationController instance. The app controller, and thus the navigation controller, can be globally accessed via a `+sharedController` like method.
2. Every view controller in the app that wishes to push a new view controller, basically does this:

   `NextViewController * nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
   [[[AppController sharedController] navigation] pushViewController:nextViewController ...];
   [nextViewController release];`

In this way, all "leaf" views are responsible for creating the next view over and pushing it, and the navigation controller lives in one place that everyone can get to.

But I cooked this up myself. Since navigation through view controllers is such a critical piece of architecture, I'm wondering if anyone has a better or more thoughtful approach here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every view controller has a `navigationController` property. If the UIViewController is part of a navigation stack, this property is set so you can grab a reference to the UINavigationController. So, instead of having to reference the AppController (or perhaps even having one at all - you can just put this in the AppDelegate), you can just do something like this:

```
NextViewController * nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController ...];
[nextViewController release];
```

Comment: Well, that makes plenty of sense. How did I miss this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `self.navigationController` in those views that need to push? The only thing you need to do in the AppController is push the initial view on the navigation controller.